# Alter script variable value from inside PowerShell function

Tags: powershell

I like C# so much better than PS but this time I'm forced to write a script...
I need to alter "global" variable from inside a function without passing the variable as parameter. Is it even possible?
Here is an abstract:

```
$a = 0
$b = 0
$c = 0
function Increment($var1, $var2)
{
$a = $var1
$b = $var2
$c++
}
```

Unlike C# in PS function variable are function scope bound and they remain unchanged outside of the scope of the function if used as described above. How can I make this work so the script variable are accessed by reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify parent scope variable using Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766722/how-to-modify-parent-scope-variable-using-powershell).

Comment: Use `$script:a` `$script:b` etc....

Comment: In general this violates the purpose of a function (alter variables outside of its own scope). You can modify variables in a parent scope, but there are usually other ways to solve the problem. Keep in mind that PowerShell can return multiple values from a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the PowerShell global variable definition:

```
$global:a = 0
$global:b = 0
$global:c = 0
function Increment($var1, $var2)
{
    $global:a = $var1
    $global:b = $var2
    $global:c++
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to modify by reference, you can use `[Ref]`, e.g.:

```
$a = 1
function inc([Ref] $v) {
  $v.Value++
}
inc ([Ref] $a)
$a  # outputs 2
```