# Powershell - persist variable outside of function

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import an xml file and store as a variable for the remainder of a powershell session. The import is obviously successful but the variable content does not persist outside of the function.

```
Function auth
{
$cred = import-clixml -Path c:\temp\cred.xml
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this:

```
Function auth
{
    $global:cred = "test"
}

auth
$global:cred
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be global, just defined outside the function scope.

Comment: not only. You can want a function for init globals variables, what is the problem. Its not the subject asked.

Comment: Well if you need function to init globals, you can do this: `$Global:Cred= auth`. Otherwise you get spaghetti code that is hard to read and maintain.

Comment: @beatcracker "*It doesn't have to be global, just defined outside the function scope*". This is actually not true. If you define `$cred = $null` outside the function and set `$cred = 'test'` inside the function, it still will not set `$cred` to `test` outside the function... try it - run this code `$cred = $null
function auth { $cred = 'test' }
$cred ` (add line breaks where needed)

Comment: There are several methods to do the same thing. In this case, a variable returned by a function, a global variable, a script variable, a variable in a database, a passage by reference, etc.

Comment: The pleasure of programming is also found in the multitude of techniques. No knowledge deserves to be rejected (as long as it does not harm others)

Answer (score 4):

You can use globals as Esperento57 suggests or you can do this

```
function auth
{
    return 'test'
}

$cred = auth
```

More succinct:

```
function auth
{
    'test'
}

$cred = auth
```

Comment: I'd ditch `return` and just output variable to the pipeline. It's the most idiomatic way.

Comment: @beatcracker I guess I use `return` because I come from a Java background... but yes, you are correct. I updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the variable outside the scope of the function first and then inside the function explicitly tell the variable to update using the `script:var` method.

---

Here's the example is taken from https://www.kongsli.net/2013/04/25/powershell-gotchas-refer-to-variables-outside-a-function/ to which credit is given.

> The thing is that we have to explicitly tell Powershell to update the variable in the parent scope instead of creating a new variable in the current scope.

```
$x = 1
function changeit {
  "Changing `$x. Was: $x"
  $script:x = 2
  "New value: $x"
}
"`$x has value $x"
changeit
"`$x has value $x"
```

Comment: well that `tell['s] Powershell to update the variable in the *script* scope`; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14685254/2518317) is how you'd specify the `parent` scope

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this but with a number of functions and variables, you can place them all into a script and then dotsource the script.

Imagine a script like this:

```
   #MyDevFunctions.ps1
   $myImportantVar = "somevar"
   $myOtherVar = "ABC123"
   Function Get-MyCoolValue(){$myImportantVar}
   Write-Host "Finished Loading MyDevFunctions"
```

If you wanted to run this, and then also persist the values of the variables and also the functions themselves, from your parent script you simply invoke it like so:

```
   PS > . .\MyDevFunctions.ps1
   "Finished Loading MyDevFunctions"

   PS > $myOtherVar
   ABC123

   PS> Get-MyCoolValue
   someVar
```